# PL/SQL Go Through All Columns And Update

Tags: oracle, replace, plsql

I want to update every column in a table, replacing `""` with `"`.

The following PL/SQL failed. Does anyone have a clue?

```
DECLARE
  COL_NAME  VARCHAR2(400);
  Cursor c1 IS
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
      FROM USER_TAB_COLS
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'COMPANY'
       AND DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2';
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;

  LOOP
   FETCH c1 INTO COL_NAME;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

   update COMPANY 
      set COL_NAME = REPLACE (COL_NAME, '""', '"')
    where COL_NAME LIKE '%""%';

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Your strategy requires dynamic sql, like `execute immediate 'update COMPANY set :COL_NAME = REPLACE (:COL_NAME, ''""'', ''"'') where :COL_NAME LIKE ''%""%''' using col_name;`. Note the doubling of the single quotes in your original statement when stringified.

Comment: Thanks, I used execute immediate and it works.